# How we can implement the same functionality of onClick of legend as we have for hover in Pie chart Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, legend

How we can implement the same functionality of onClick of legend as we have for hover in Pie chart in Highcharts?

I want to implement the same functionality on click of legend as we have for hover.
eg. When we hover on any legend in pie chart, we show the corresponding pie segment and blur the other segment of pie chart. I want the feature with legends also. So that when I click on any legend, It should highlight the corresponding section and blur the other segments. Also show tooltip when I click on legend.

*Current behaviour when click on legend* - hides the corresponding section.

*Expected behaviour when click on legend* - highlight the corresponding section and show tooltip.

I have the solution for showing tooltip when click on legend but don't have the solution for "highlight the corresponding section and blurring the other segments".

Any help would be appreciable. I am looking for the solution as quick as possible.

Thank you in advance! :)

Below is the link for codesandbox where I am trying to implement above usecase.
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fire-4smdrt?file=/src/App.js:3352-3356

Comment: It would be useful to include some code and/or show some attempt(s). Take a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and its linked resources for more info.

Comment: Sure @Reyno, Please find the link am trying to implement above thing.
link - https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-fire-4smdrt?file=/src/App.js:3352-3356

Comment: It seems, that my colleague has already answered your question on forum topic here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=48882 In the future, please do not duplicate your question in multiple support channels.

Comment: okay @magdalena :)